# How can I specify where my local developer's service fabric cluster is created?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

My problem: I am learning Service Fabric, and doing simple tutorials, and the local cluster is filling up my C drive. I run the projects in Visual Studio. It first creates a cluster in a folder SfDevCluster. That takes up 842 MB of space. Then it deploys the services and web api sites. Remember, these are trivial tutorials with almost nothing in them. Now, I notice that I have a folder with a Size = 1.22 TB and Size on Disk of 9.4 GB. I'm not sure how to interpret that. But it consumes the remaining space on my C drive and sets off alarms. 
I have other drives with lots of space. I would love to specify that those be used. Is there a way to do that with the service fabric cluster used by Visual Studio?  Or is there a way to constrain the overly ambitious size allocations? And if you understand this, can you explain what these unusual folder sizes mean?
In the old days, I would have a hard drive with lots of space. But now, my developer machine has a much faster, but more expensive SSD drive, and space is at a premium. So I need more control of the cluster location.

Comment: I have tried dew options (also want to avoid it eating up my SSD), best option I found is using directory symlinks (`mklink /D`)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can set up a local cluster pointing to a non-system drive by running the DevClusterSetup script in PowerShell. You can find the script under `%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\`. The command line you want is:

`.\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -PathToClusterDataRoot <desired_app_and_data_location> -PathToClusterLogRoot <desired_tracelog_location>`

If you already have a cluster running, this script will remove it and create a new one (note that this will delete any deployed apps and their data). Once you have the new cluster running, Visual Studio will automatically use that when you deploy locally.

As for the file sizes - this is mostly due to the log file used for replication of state stored in reliable collections. A large, [sparse file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365564(v=vs.85).aspx) is preallocated up-front, which is why you see a difference between size and size on disk. We are planning to make these values configurable so that they can be dialed down on local clusters.

Comment: Just to help anyone who just did what I did, this needs to be run in x64 powershell as admin

Comment: Works fine, but it eventually changes back to the default folder. Why?

Comment: I had it reset back to my C drive too, @RaulKist.  It was because I used the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager (i.e. the circle thing in the taskbar you can right-click on) to reset, rather than the script above, I think.  So whenever you reset you should always use the above command instead.

Comment: @rrreee, I used the script :( Perhaps they fixed it. I should give it a new try.

Comment: Take a look below to resolve an issue with the paths reset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294380/1964969

Comment: I  am using Ubuntu 16 for development. I have deployed a node application. Still in my local sfdevcluster folder inside data  30GB has been used and increase day by day by 2-3 GB. How can I stop this  ?

Answer (score 21):

In the Service Fabric SDK folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\ServiceFabric), you will find a ClusterSetup folder.

In there you will find ClusterManifestTemplate.json files for the different configurations of the local cluster. These are json configuration files used by the powershell scripts that create and manage the local service fabric cluster.

At the bottom of these files, in "fabricSettings" it is setting the value of the FabricDataRoot and FabricLogRoot, based on the "%systemDrive%". If you replace this by "D:" it should result in a local cluster on the D drive.

After making these changes, I stopped my local fabric, deleted the current fabric folders from my C drive, and rebooted my machine. When I then start a debug session in VS.2017, it creates the local dev fabric on my D drive and deploys the application to that location. (I do notice that some empty folders are created on my C drive but these are not used.)

Comment: Yeah. It still works em 2021. Please note that there 1-node and 5-node json files to update.

Answer (score 0):

What you also can do is resetting the local cluster once in a while.

Can be easily done using the `Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager` application:

[image: sf reset local cluster]