# Local deployment — change the default location

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

How / where do I specify the location for the deployment of my local cluster/application? I would like to change the default location to another local drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the DevClusterSetup powershell script, located (at least for me) in `C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Service Fabric/ClusterSetup/`

You want to run the script as follows:
`.\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -PathToClusterDataRoot <desired_app_and_data_location>`

Thanks to Sean McKenna [How can I specify where my local developer's service fabric cluster is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959643/how-can-i-specify-where-my-local-developers-service-fabric-cluster-is-created)